# What is the use of "Advertising ID" ? What do I have to do after getting "Advertising ID"?

Tags: android, ads

What is the use of Android "Advertising ID" (AAID) ? what i have to do after getting "Advertising ID" (AAID) in android programmatically . please any one explain about this . thank you in advance.

Anybody guys can you give me some suggestions , how to get user interests by a using android Advertising ID

Answer (score 1):

Advertising ID

The advertising ID is a unique, user-resettable ID for advertising, provided by Google Play services. It gives users better controls and provides developers with a simple, standard system to continue to monetize their apps. It enables users to reset their identifier or opt out of personalized ads (formerly known as interest-based ads) within Google Play apps.

[Click to see what is about AAID define by Play Store Console!](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=en)

[How to Implement that!](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient)

## 'Advertising ID' will help you to do jobs bellow..

**1.** The Android advertising identifier must only be used for advertising and user analytics. The status of the “Opt out of Interest-based Advertising” or “Opt out of Ads Personalization” setting must be verified on each access of the ID.

**2.** Association with personally-identifiable information or other identifiers. The advertising identifier must not be connected to personally-identifiable information or associated with any persistent device identifier (for example: SSAID, MAC address, IMEI, etc.) without explicit consent of the user.

**3.** Respecting users' selections. If reset, a new advertising identifier must not be connected to a previous advertising identifier or data derived from a previous advertising identifier without the explicit consent of the user. Also, you must abide by a user’s “Opt out of Interest-based Advertising” or “Opt out of Ads Personalization” setting. If a user has enabled this setting, you may not use the advertising identifier for creating user profiles for advertising purposes or for targeting users with personalized advertising. Allowed activities include contextual advertising, frequency capping, conversion tracking, reporting and security and fraud detection.

**4.** Transparency to users. The collection and use of the advertising identifier and commitment to these terms must be disclosed to users in a legally adequate privacy notification. To learn more about our privacy standards, please review our User Data policy.

**5.** Abiding by the terms of use. The advertising identifier may only be used in accordance with these terms, including by any party that you may share it with in the course of your business. All apps uploaded or published to Google Play must use the advertising ID (when available on a device) in lieu of any other device identifiers for any advertising purposes.

**Now Its up to you. What you want to do!**

Comment: thank you for reply. yes i read this i'm getting **Advertising ID** also. after that what i have to do with that id?